# scrapy-splash not rendering dynamic content generated by thirdparty script(plugin)

Tags: scrapy, splash-screen, scrapy-splash

I am trying to scrape webpages reviews.. For example:

https://www.chubbiesshorts.com/products/the-arnolds

Here the reviews are generated by plugin, running its script. I can not render those dynamic content using splash, nor the content is being render in splash UI("http://localhost:8050/info?wait=0.5&images=1&expand=1&timeout=3600.0&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.chubbiesshorts.com%2Fproducts%2Fthe-arnolds&lua_source=function+main%28splash%2C+args%29%0D%0A++assert%28splash%3Ago%28args.url%29%29%0D%0A++assert%28splash%3Await%28150%29%29%0D%0A++return+%7B%0D%0A++++html+%3D+splash%3Ahtml%28%29%2C%0D%0A++++png+%3D+splash%3Apng%28%29%2C%0D%0A++++har+%3D+splash%3Ahar%28%29%2C%0D%0A++%7D%0D%0Aend").

Can anyone help me to get those content.

Comment: I faced similar problem but was never able to fix it :(